# Find array key in php and change its value or contents?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given a multi-dimensional array that you don't necessarily know the structure of; how would one search for a key by name and change or add to it's contents? The value of the key could be either a string or an array and the effects should be applied either way--I had looked at array_walk_recursive, but it ignores anything that contains another array...

Comment: This question lacks clarity because it is missing a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
function arrayWalkFullRecursive(&$array, $callback, $userdata = NULL) {
    call_user_func($callback, $value, $key, $userdata);

    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
        arrayWalkFullRecursive($value);
    }

    return true;
}

arrayWalkFullRecursive($array,
    create_function(                // wtb PHP 5.3
        '&$value, $key, $data',
        'if($key == $data['key']) {
             $value = $data['value'];
         }'
    ),
    array('key' => 'foo', 'value' => 'bar')
);
```

Comment: Didn't quite work, but got me on the right track. I put together a function called remove_recursive() for removing array items, now I need to make the add_recursive() and change_recursive(). :)

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Array keys in PHP are ints and strings.  You can't have an array array key.  So yeah, `array_walk_recursive()` is what you want.

Comment: I mean the value that corresponds with the key. If the value is another level of array it will skip it and recurse inward until it finds something with a non-array value.