# Edit an array with new values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [datas] => Array
        (
            [General] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => logo
                            [size] => 10
                        )
                )
            [Rooms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => room_1
                            [size] => 8
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => room_2
                            [size] => 8
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => room_3
                            [size] => 8
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I need to update it when I receive some info like this:

```
$key = 'room_3';
$toChange = '9';
```

So in my array, I want to change the `size` of `room_3`.

**I will always edit the same element (i.e. `size`).**

---

**What I tried:**

```
// Function to communicate with the array
getDatas($array, 'room_3', '9');

function getDatas($datas, $got, $to_find) {
    foreach ($datas as $d) {
        if (array_search($got, $d)) {
            if (in_array($to_find, array_keys($d))) {
                return trim($d[$to_find]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work...

Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work? How doesn't it work?

Comment: Is $array a 3-dimensional or 2-dimensional array at all? How can you just foreach one time to check a 3-dimensional value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find array key in php and change its value or contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344698/find-array-key-in-php-and-change-its-value-or-contents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getDatas($datas, $got, $to_find) {
    foreach($datas['datas'] as $key => $rows) {
        foreach($rows as $number => $row) {
            if($row['id'] == $got) {
                // u can return new value
                return $row['size'];
                // or you can change it and return update array
                $datas['dates'][$key][$number]['size'] = $to_find; // it should be sth like $new value
                return $datas;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be [datas].

Answer (score 0):

It's a 3-dimensional array, if you want to change the value, do like this:

```
$key = 'room_3';
$toChange = '9';

$array['datas'] = getRooms($array['datas'], $key, $toChange);

function getRooms($rooms, $key, $toChange) {
    foreach($rooms as $k1=>$v1) foreach ($v1 as $k2=>$v2) {
        if ($v2['id'] == $key)) {
           $rooms[$k1][$k2]['size'] = $toChange;
        }
    }
    return $rooms;
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Rooms is a dynamic value.

Comment: @moutarde Then you can foreach it twice. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeRoomSize (&$datas, $roomID, $newSize ){

        //assuming that you have provided valid data in $datas array

        foreach($datas['datas']['Rooms'] as &$room){
            if($room['id'] == $roomID){

                $room['size'] = $newSize;
                break;//you can add break to stop looping after the room size is changed
            }
        }

    }
    //--- > define here your array with data

    //and then call this function
    changeRoomSize($data,"room_3",9);

    //print the results
    var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I must loop in all the array as Rooms could be dynamic.